# Can't Access newly installed redis(5.0.5) on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: redis

I newly installed Ubuntu 19.10, and installed redis with `sudo apt install redis-server`(5.0.5).
And started `sudo systemctl start redis`.
Executed `redis-cli`, then I got `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Y`

The last 1 charactor (`Y` in this case) is different each time.
I just installed with using apt and didn't change any configs.

Is there any bugs or something I missed? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install from source code (5.0.7).
It works.